# Faster way to save checkboxes to sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where I would like to apply checkboxes to a few ranges. I made a rangeList and then use the following code:

```
  //apply checkboxes to entire boolean rangeList
  var activeRanges = compSheet.getRangeList(rangeListArr).activate();
  activeRanges.insertCheckboxes();
```

But this is incredibly slow. Even with one row in the range it takes around one second to apply the checkbox to each column. I used rangeList because I thought it might work faster than applying checkboxes to individual ranges but there seems to be no difference in speed.

Comment: What does your RangeList look like? If contiguous Range.insertCheckboxes() may be better https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertCheckboxes(Object)

Comment: Hi. Something like [ 'C1:C100', 'J1:J100', 'Z1:Z100']

Comment: How many checkboxes do you have?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my answer was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. In this case, I thought that my answer was not useful for your situation. So I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I have to study more and more.

Comment: Hello Tanaike. Actually I am a big fan of yours and Have used many of your solutions in the past. Your solution also taught me some new functions so there was no need to delete it. I am sorry you were offended that I didn't select it. I selected the other one only because it was indeed faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will divide the time by about 2 without `activate()`

```
const compSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5')
var activeRanges = compSheet.getRangeList(rangeListArr).insertCheckboxes();
```

It seems to run faster than batchupdate following a few tests.

### edit

Here are 3 tests and their perfomance in millisecondes

```
function test1(){
  // 703 MILLISECONDS
  var d = new Date()
  var rangeListArr = ['C1:C100', 'J1:J100', 'Z1:Z100']; 
  const compSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5')
  var activeRanges = compSheet.getRangeList(rangeListArr).activate();
  activeRanges.insertCheckboxes();
  Logger.log(new Date() - d)
}

function test2(){
  // 348 MILLISECONDS
  var d = new Date()
  var rangeListArr = ['C1:C100', 'J1:J100', 'Z1:Z100']; 
  const compSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5')
  var activeRanges = compSheet.getRangeList(rangeListArr).insertCheckboxes();
  Logger.log(new Date() - d)
}

function test3() {
  // 469 MILLISECONDS
  var d = new Date()
  const rangeListArr = ['C1:C100', 'J1:J100', 'Z1:Z100']; 
  const sheetName = "Sheet5"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const requests = sheet.getRangeList(rangeListArr).getRanges().map(r => {
    const startRowIndex = r.getRow() - 1;
    const startColumnIndex = r.getColumn() - 1;
    const endRowIndex = startRowIndex + r.getNumRows();
    const endColumnIndex = startColumnIndex + r.getNumColumns();
    return { repeatCell: { range: { sheetId, startRowIndex, endRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endColumnIndex }, cell: { dataValidation: { condition: { type: "BOOLEAN" } } }, fields: "dataValidation" } };
  });
  if (requests.length > 0) {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
  }
  Logger.log(new Date() - d)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I made this change. It was marginally faster. I think actually my problem lies elsewhere. Still investigating.

Comment: You are right, however I don't find something faster. Let me know if you find a new way. I have added my exprience in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I marked yours as the correct answer after the speed tests.